# Error java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in Google Map V2

Tags: android, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Map V2 API for the map. I have copied the google-play-services.jar in libs folder and set in the build path of eclipse.

I am getting exception as I added logcat.

Please help to get solve this issue.

home_map_view.xml

```
<fragment
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.app.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY"/>

       <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
           android:configChanges="orientation" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".HomeMapView" android:label="@string/title_home" android:configChanges="orientation" android:launchMode="singleTop" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

HomeMapView.java

```
public class HomeMapView extends FragmentActivity implements OnTabChangeListener {

    private GoogleMap mapView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_map_view);

        // Getting reference to SupportMapFragment of the activity_main
        SupportMapFragment fragment = new SupportMapFragment(); 
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction() .add(R.id.map, fragment).commit(); 

        // Getting Map for the SupportMapFragment
        mapView = fragment.getMap();
        mapView.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Logcat:

```
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.HomeMapView}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class fragment
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:587)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:216)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1660)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at com.example.app.HomeMapView.onCreate(HomeMapView.java:61)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    ... 11 more
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782): Caused by: android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:395)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:363)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:264)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    ... 20 more
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.example.app-2.apk]
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:385)
05-15 23:17:52.843: E/AndroidRuntime(19782):    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You problem is the way you added `google-play-services` to your project:

> I have copied the google-play-services.jar in libs folder and set in the build path of eclipse.

This is wrong! 
Read the first 3 steps of this blog post I wrote to get an idea of how to do it correctly:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

In short, you should import `google-play-services` as a project in your workspace.
and then reference it from your project.

this should be the result:

[image]

Comment: @Emil Adz I am getting this exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable.

Comment: have you committed all the steps described in the Guide?

Comment: @user1996510  i guess you have not referred to google play services library properly still.

Comment: +1 Well Done!!!Solved my problem..Getting this issue from last two days.Now solved.It would be helpful for others.

Comment: @Emil Adz Can you help me in how can i draw route between two location in Google Map V2.

Comment: take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125868/draw-driving-route-between-2-geopoints-on-googlemap-supportmapfragment/16126547#16126547

Comment: @Emil Adz Can I set the margin of fragment programmatically at runtime. Please suggest me to do this. I need this.

Comment: I never done that programmatically, open a new question for this. I'm sure you will be helped.

Comment: Today i updated my google play service lib to rev 7, but there is a problem. It builds google play service normally but there is no jar file in bin folder.

Comment: @EmilAdz Your blog is outdated and no longer relevant for current Google Play Services. It now includes individual libraries (in aar format) for each of the desired services, which need to be extracted and converted to individual library projects. The new manifest meta-data is ```com.google.android.geo.API_KEY``` but uses the same key. This could be why others would think you gave an incorrect answer.

Answer (score 11):

Use support Map fragment in place of Map fragment. Make sure you have added the support libray

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment "
  android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>
```

Second you should not copy the jar file to your build path.

You should refer the google play services library project in your map project.

Import your library project to your worksace. import the same to eclipse.

Right click on your project. goto properties. Choose android. click android. browse and add the library project.

[image]

Comment: @EmilAdz i din't see your post and edit my answer. I am sorry if you feel that way. I already started editing even before you posted the answer. since you could not see my edit you thought otherwise

Comment: @EmilAdz  i posted the answer and then started to edit. could you see while i was editing. in mean time you posted the answer. By the time you could see my update you thought i copied form your answer. I am sorry its not that way. If you feel that way i will upvote your answer. you take the credit

Comment: i can't help if you feel it that way. I din't edit my answer seeing your post.

Comment: Well, never mind. @Raghunandan. I got the feeling that this is the way it was.

Comment: @EmilAdz could you delete the comment coz someone downvoted the answer probably seeing at your comment. even i don't get a upvote from now on i don't want any more downvotes

Answer (score 0):

> If everything is woking same as google code then please check manifest file in my case i added geo key and map key that's why exception occurs,

**Note - do not add two keys in manifest file remove map key**

```
meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key"/>
```

add this code.

```
 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/auto_location"/>

 <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```