# InflateException while trying to display a Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm getting mad about this problem! It has already been discussed many times but nothing seems to work for me. I'm just trying to display a map in my activity.
Here are my files:
MapTest.java

```
package it.michele.pedometer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MapTest extends FragmentActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    }

}
```

map_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/><br>
```

manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.michele.pedometer"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="it.michele.pedometer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="it.michele.pedometer.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/walking_man"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="it.michele.pedometer.Pedometer"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="it.michele.pedometer.MapTest"
            android:label="asd"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myKey..." />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried it on an emulator with API 16 and this is the LogCat:

```
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{it.michele.pedometer/it.michele.pedometer.MapTest}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at it.michele.pedometer.MapTest.onCreate(MapTest.java:12)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     ... 11 more
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:584)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:552)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4656)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     ... 20 more
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:574)
09-11 20:33:41.319: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     ... 23 more
```

Any idea on how to solve the problem? Thank you!

## **EDIT**

I made this changes:
I referenced the google-play-services.jar as an external jar
map_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

MapTest.java

```
package it.michele.pedometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MapTest extends Activity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_layout);
    }

}
```

LogCat

```
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown Source)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.onInflate(Unknown Source)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4663)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at it.michele.pedometer.MapTest.onCreate(MapTest.java:12)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-11 20:56:32.180: E/AndroidRuntime(1358):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real cause of the problem is

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

see your complete stack trace

### Solution

You need to add `google-play-services.jar` correctly, see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried so but when I close the properties window and re-open it there is a red cross which signals some problems with the dependency. What can be the cause?

Comment: Ok I finally solved the problem: I just closed and restarted Eclipse and the google-play-services project reference stayed "green-tick". So the app is starting but just showing a white screen. Do I need to open a new question or is there a quick solution? My device is a Samsung Galaxy Gio with Android 2.3.7 (Cyanogenmod)

Comment: best thing would be to create a new question, andbefore that close this question by marking any answer as correct

Comment: Ok I solved it completely. It turned out that I had enable Google Maps API v2 instead of Google Maps Android API v2. Once again, thank you everyone!