# Difficulty in opening an activity related to google map in android

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am very new to android and I got this app of e contact on net but whenever I try to open  any activity such as fire station but this app crashes.

This is the code of the fire station activity which will be called after clicking on fire station imageview

```
package shravan.nyshadh.balaji;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

/**
 * In this activity, emergency icons are drawn according to the view that was clicked
 * from MainActivity. Icons are numbered in order of increasing distance 
 * from user's current location.
 *
 */
public class Maps extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap myMap;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationListener locationListener;
    Location mLoc;
    int code;
    boolean zoomb = true;
    ArrayList<String> ambulances = new ArrayList<String>();
    boolean directioncheck = false;

    // LIST VIEW
    ListView listview;
    ArrayList<String> itemlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<Marker> markerlist;

    Direction direction = new Direction();
    ArrayList<LatLng> pline = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    LatLng currentmarker;
    Integer cid;

    String provider = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);


        /*
         * Check if any of the radios (Mobile Data or Wi-Fi) are on. 
         */
        final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == 0 && wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() == false && manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) == false) {
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Maps.this);
            ad.setTitle("First-Responder");
            ad.setMessage("Your network and gps providers are off. Please enable one of them.");
            ad.setPositiveButton("Network", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    AlertDialog.Builder network = new AlertDialog.Builder(Maps.this);
                    network.setTitle("First-Responder");
                    network.setMessage("Please choose between Wi-Fi and Mobile Data");
                    network.setPositiveButton("Wi-Fi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            provider = "network";
                        }
                    });
                    network.setNegativeButton("Mobile Data", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Intent intent = new Intent (android.provider.Settings.ACTION_DATA_ROAMING_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            provider = "network";
                        }
                    });
                    network.show();
                }
            });
            ad.setNegativeButton("GPS", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    provider = "gps";
                }
            });
            ad.show();
        }

        if(telephonyManager.getDataState() == TelephonyManager.DATA_CONNECTED) {
            provider = "network";
        } else if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            provider = "network";
        } else if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            provider = "gps";
        }

        listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemlist);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        markerlist = new ArrayList<Marker>();

        FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SupportMapFragment mySupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        myMap = mySupportMapFragment.getMap();
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        code = intent.getIntExtra("key", 0);

        if (provider != null) {
            mLoc = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }

        if (mLoc != null) {
            query(mLoc);
        }

        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(markerlist.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                LatLng point = markerlist.get(position).getPosition();
                CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                myMap.animateCamera(center, 2000, null);
            }
        });
        myMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfoWindowClick(final Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(Maps.this);
                ad.setTitle("First-Responder");
                ad.setMessage("Would you like directions?");
                ad.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        myMap.clear();
                        query(mLoc);
                        currentmarker = marker.getPosition();
                        LatLng pt = marker.getPosition();
                        direction.getmapsinfo(myMap, pt, mLoc, itemlist, adapter);
                        listview.setClickable(false);
                    }
                });
                ad.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        //ok, do nothing
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });
                ad.show();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * This method takes in a parameter loc, which is the user's current location. Then, according to the view
     * pressed from MainActivity the according case is executed. The method performs a Google nearby search and
     * returns a JSON String for parsing.
     * @param loc
     */
    public void query(Location loc) {
        switch (code) {
        case 1:
            new GetHospitals()
                    .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLatitude())
                            + ","
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLongitude())
                            + "&rankby=distance&types=hospital&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAPrOxAoTKUdaXtktg4B2QrdPZO5SpM0VQ");
            break;
        case 2:
            new GetHospitals()
                    .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLatitude())
                            + ","
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLongitude())
                            + "&rankby=distance&types=police&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAPrOxAoTKUdaXtktg4B2QrdPZO5SpM0VQ");
            break;
        case 3:
            new GetHospitals()
                    .execute("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location="
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLatitude())
                            + ","
                            + Double.toString(mLoc.getLongitude())
                            + "&rankby=distance&types=fire_station&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAPrOxAoTKUdaXtktg4B2QrdPZO5SpM0VQ");
            break;
        case 4:
            Database db = new Database(Maps.this);
            LatLng point = new LatLng(mLoc.getLatitude(), mLoc.getLongitude());
            ambulances = db.sort(point);
            placemarkers(ambulances);
            db.close();
            break;
        }
    }


    /**
     * Assigns a number according to distance the nearest ambulance.
     * @param ambulances
     */
    private void placemarkers(ArrayList<String> ambulances){
        Bitmap myWrittenBitmap;     
        for(int i = 0; i < ambulances.size(); i++){
            String item = ambulances.get(i);
            Marker m;
            myWrittenBitmap = customImage(i+1, R.drawable.ambulance_launcher);

            String[] values = item.split(",");
            String name = values[0];
            String number = values[1];
            String itemlat = values[2];
            String itemlong = values[3];

            LatLng point = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(itemlat), Double.parseDouble(itemlong));
            m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(name).snippet(number).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myWrittenBitmap)));
            markerlist.add(m);
            if(!directioncheck){
                itemlist.add(Integer.toString(i+1)+"  "+ name);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        LatLng point = new LatLng(mLoc.getLatitude(), mLoc.getLongitude());
        CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);
        myMap.moveCamera(center);
        myMap.animateCamera(zoom);
    }


    /**
     * This method takes in an index and a picture (represented as an int) 
     * and creates a canvas on which to paint and write the number on.
     * @param index
     * @param resource
     * @return bitmap
     */
    // adding custom images to markers.
    private Bitmap customImage(int index, int resource ){
        Bitmap bm;
        Bitmap myWrittenBitmap;
        Canvas canvas;
        Paint txtPaint;

        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resource);
        myWrittenBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm.getWidth(), bm.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
        // create a Canvas on which to draw and a Paint to write text.
        canvas = new Canvas(myWrittenBitmap);
        txtPaint = new Paint();
        txtPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        txtPaint.setTextSize(12);
        txtPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        txtPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
        //draw ref bitmap then text on our canvas
        canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawText(Integer.toString(index), 10,10 , txtPaint);
        return myWrittenBitmap;

    }

    private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            if (loc != null) {
                mLoc = new Location(loc);
                //query(mLoc);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Context context = Maps.this;
            AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            ad.setTitle("Warning!");
            ad.setMessage("Provider: " + provider + " disabled");
            if(provider.equals("network")) {
                String button1String = "Enable network";
                ad.setPositiveButton(button1String, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int arg1) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            }
            ad.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.maps, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public String readConnectionString(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("ConnectionString", "Failed to connect");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ConnectionString", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    private class GetHospitals extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return readConnectionString(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String JSONString) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);
                JSONArray EmergencyItems = new JSONArray(
                        jsonObject.getString("results"));
                for (int i = 0; i < EmergencyItems.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject EmergencyItem = EmergencyItems.getJSONObject(i);
                    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(EmergencyItem
                            .getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location").getString("lat"));
                    Double lng = Double.parseDouble(EmergencyItem
                            .getJSONObject("geometry")
                            .getJSONObject("location").getString("lng"));
                    LatLng point = new LatLng(lat,lng);
                    Bitmap myWrittenBitmap;
                    Marker m;
                    switch (code) {
                    case 1:
                        myWrittenBitmap = customImage(i+1, R.drawable.hsp_launcher);
                         m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(EmergencyItem.getString("name")).snippet(EmergencyItem.getString("vicinity")).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myWrittenBitmap)));
                        if(directioncheck == false){
                            itemlist.add(Integer.toString(i+1)+"  "+ EmergencyItem.getString("name"));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        markerlist.add(m);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        myWrittenBitmap = customImage(i+1, R.drawable.pol_launcher);
                        m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(EmergencyItem.getString("name")).snippet(EmergencyItem.getString("vicinity")).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myWrittenBitmap)));
                        if(directioncheck == false){
                            itemlist.add(Integer.toString(i+1)+"  "+ EmergencyItem.getString("name"));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        markerlist.add(m);
                        break;
                    case 3:                     
                        myWrittenBitmap = customImage(i+1, R.drawable.fire_launcher);
                        m = myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title(EmergencyItem.getString("name")).snippet(EmergencyItem.getString("vicinity")).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(myWrittenBitmap)));
                        if(directioncheck == false){
                            itemlist.add(Integer.toString(i+1)+"  "+ EmergencyItem.getString("name"));
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                        markerlist.add(m);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(zoomb) {
                    LatLng point = new LatLng(mLoc.getLatitude(), mLoc.getLongitude());
                    CameraUpdate center = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point);
                    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(12);
                    myMap.moveCamera(center);
                    myMap.animateCamera(zoom);
                    zoomb=false;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("EmergencyItem", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    /** used upon resuming the application. 
     *
     */
    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
//      if(provider == "network") {
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
//      } else if (provider == "gps") {
//          lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
//      }
        Log.v(null, "Maps's onResume Method !!!");      
    }
    /**
     * Android onPause method. Clears any stored location in location manager.
     */
    @Override
    public void onPause(){
        super.onPause();
        lm.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        zoomb = true;
        Log.v(null, "Maps's onPause Method !!!");
    }

    /**
     * Android onSaveInstanceState method. Here, the
     * driving instructions, latitudes and longitudes
     * are stored.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(direction.getDirections() != null){
            Log.v("!NullDirection", "!NULL");
            outState.putStringArrayList("DIRECTIONS", direction.getDirections());
            Preferences.writeLatLng(this, Preferences.MLAT, currentmarker);
        } else {
            Log.v("NullDirection", "NULL");
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inputState){
        Log.v("INRESTORE", "onRestoreInstanceState");
        if(inputState != null){
            if(inputState.containsKey("DIRECTIONS")){
                itemlist.clear();
                //adapter.clear();
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,itemlist);
                ArrayList<String> tempitemlist = inputState.getStringArrayList("DIRECTIONS");
                Log.v("FIRST DIRECTION", Integer.toString(itemlist.size()));
                for(int i = 0; i < tempitemlist.size(); i++){
                    itemlist.add(tempitemlist.get(i));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                directioncheck = true;
            }
            if(Preferences.readMarker(this, Preferences.MLAT) != null){
                LatLng pts = Preferences.readMarker(this, Preferences.MLAT);
                currentmarker = pts;
                direction.getmapsinfo(myMap, pts, mLoc, itemlist, adapter);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the logcat**

```
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):
     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions.createFromAttributes(Unknown
     Source) 08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onInflate(Unknown
     Source) 08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:279)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:270)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     shravan.nyshadh.balaji.Maps.onCreate(Maps.java:86) 08-18 16:02:05.509:
     E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 08-18 16:02:05.509:
     E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 08-18 16:02:05.509:
     E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
     08-18 16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):    at
     com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560) 08-18
     16:02:05.509: E/AndroidRuntime(3578):  at
     dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This is the **xml** of the **map activity**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fare_check_frame"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="316dp"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: Sakshi, please post your error code here.

Comment: Sorry what do mean by error code the log cat or anything else??

Comment: Did u import Google Play Services Library ?

Comment: Have you checked that In your Xml file you have also took supportMapFragment and not only mapfragment?

Comment: @sakshi yes logcat, I was meant to say

Comment: @sakshi I ahve seen it, please paste your xml file here

Comment: Try wit below part of code: <fragment
        android:id="@+id/maps"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: I added the above code in the manifest file inside application tag but it is still not working.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment

Comment: @sakshi yu have to add that code in your xml file