# ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment and SupportMapFragment using Google Map API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to show Map in my application and tried it using Google Map API v2. But I am facing a problem ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment at runtime. Bellow is the code.

1. **Activity Class**:

   `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity 
   {
       MapFragment mapFragment;
       SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       }
   }`

   2. **XML layout**

   ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
   ```

   3. **manifest file**

   ```
    <uses-sdk
       android:maxSdkVersion="19"
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true" />

   <permission
       android:name="com.xerces.mapsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.xerces.mapsample.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="MAP API KEY" />
   </application>
   ```

I am using google play service library in my project as per mention in tutorials or android developers guide.

So could any body help me on this. I have wasted my too much time on this.

Bellow screenshot contains my library structure...
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment

Comment: Yes it may be duplicate. but there is no such answer which will solve my question. Because i am not using .jar file. I have added google play service lib properly in my project.

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
}
```