# Error inflating class fragment, android map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

This question have been asked many more times, and i have tried almost all the solutions given there but nothing worked in my case. This is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>
```

this is my java code

```
public class Storesearch extends FragmentActivity{
  private GoogleMap map; 
  private LocationManager locationManager;
  private Location mylocation;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_storesearch);
    determineLocation();
  }

  protected void onStart() {
       super.onStart();
       setupMap();
       appMapSettings();
       spotCurrentLocation(mylocation);
  }

  public void setupMap(){
   if(map==null){
     SupportMapFragment mf=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);   
      map=mf.getMap();

   }

  }
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.fyp.searchstore"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission
        android:name="com.fyp.searchstore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.fyp.searchstore.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="API KEY"/>

     <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="19" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Storesearch"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    </manifest>
```

and finally my logcat report

```
10-17 04:45:12.664: D/AndroidRuntime(2461): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:45:12.664: W/dalvikvm(2461): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb2ad1ba8)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): Process: com.fyp.searchstore, PID: 2461
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fyp.searchstore/com.fyp.searchstore.Storesearch}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-17 04:45:12.684: E/AndroidRuntime(2461):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

its giving me error on second line of xml file. i m using revision20 of google play services while my android API is version 19. Does the problem i m having is due to these versions? Thanks in advance

Comment: Try with this line of code: android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" instead of "class" attribute.

Comment: @pratik i have tried this, but didn't worked :(

Comment: Shifa, are you testing it on emulator or on device?

Comment: im tesing it on emulator of target Google APIs - API evel 19

Comment: I think it will not work with emulator, please test once on real device and check if its working or not?

Comment: Even i have tested it on a real device but still its not working :( any other solution?

Comment: Why you have not given meta-data tag in your menifest file?? Or if you can send me your code then let me solve it and will send back to you, if u dnt mind.

Comment: <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="4030500" /> replace this and check what you getting?

Comment: yup, where should i send you?

Comment: @pratik sent on your mail.

Comment: Ok Shifa, let me check

Comment: I have not got your mail, please check it again.

Comment: oh, i have sent it again, check now

Comment: got it, working on it

Comment: Sent you email, please check it and reply me

Comment: Your error solved, sending you mail now.

Comment: have you solved this one?

Comment: yeap i have solved this one but getting a new one

Comment: What you getting now?

Comment: jar mismatch error not leaving my life !

Comment: ohhoo still you getting errors?

Comment: yes! once the map has appeared but when i did further work , the same error came again

Comment: I think its the issue in your map sdk and support sdk.

Comment: pataaa naeeee :( sab try karlia but of no use

Comment: you can ask me for a help if you want any.

Comment: i will mail you the full details of problem :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26755514/list-items-not-showing-when-reading-data-from-sqlite-db

Comment: shifa, ok mail me and are you using whats app?

Answer (score 0):

Look like this guy had the same problem than you: [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment)
Look to the second answer. Did you copy the *.jar* file or did you add it as a referenced library ?

And had you download the Android Support Library ?

Answer (score 0):

hello are you trying to check it on android emulator? if yes than please use google-api emulator which will have support library in it. try to check in real android device and if its still giving you same error than add google play services in your project also.

Comment: YES m testing it on google API emuator and also have added google play services in my project but still having the problem

Comment: if you have real android device than try to test on that. it will sure run on that. i too had same problem and when i run it on device than it gives me map. and when i tried to run in emulator than it gives me error in inflating class.