# Application get crashed at starting in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

iam buildding android app on eclipse and when i want to run the app on my android device this message appears:
unfortunately ,testm has stopped .

this is the log cat:

```
04-04 18:00:01.201: I/Process(28482): Sending signal. PID: 28482 SIG: 9
04-04 18:00:24.531: W/ApplicationPackageManager(28715):        getCSCPackageItemText()
04-04 18:00:24.531: I/PersonaManager(28715): getPersonaService() name persona_policy
04-04 18:00:24.561: D/AndroidRuntime(28715): Shutting down VM
04-04 18:00:24.561: W/dalvikvm(28715): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4181bc08)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): Process: com.example.testm, PID: 28715
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): java.lang.RuntimeException:  Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.testm/com.example.testm.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class   fragment
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:161)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1265)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at  android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class fragment
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:719)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:359)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2015)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at com.example.testm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5431)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    ... 11 more
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment: make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:597)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:561)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4969)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:695)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    ... 21 more
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715): Caused by:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" on path: DexPathList[[zip file  "/data/app/com.example.testm-9.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.testm-9, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:583)
04-04 18:00:24.566: E/AndroidRuntime(28715):    ... 24 more
```

and mainctivity.java:

```
      package com.example.testm;

      import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.MenuItem;

      public class MainActivity extends Activity {
       @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      }

       @Override
      public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
      }

       @Override
       public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
       // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
       // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
      // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
       int id = item.getItemId();
       if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
          return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
      }
```

and main_activity.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout                     
    xmlns:andr  oid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testm.MainActivity" >

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />



     <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is probably an error of project setup, not anything wrong with your code (and unfortunately you can't put your project setup in an SO post!), or else running on a device/emulator which doesn't have Google's proprietary APIs available.   See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572020/error-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-android-gms-maps-mapfragment for an Eclipse-era explanation, there's probably an Android studio version around here somewhere too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : "Eclipse-era" - lol. Until Android Studio grows up a bit I'm personally mostly happy to stick with with Eclipse

Comment: Can you post the code of fragment class ?

Comment: i did not add any thing on fragmnet class it is just the first time to me to try display google map on my projet