# Getting navigation using google map Version 2 -- Android

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

I am pretty new to google map version 2. I can able to get ride of getting location and tracking my location. i have more focused on this, is there a way to implement voice based navigation using this api. i dint get any proper guidance. +1 for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a visual navigation on the map using the Google Direction API and paint polylines on the map. Take a look at this answer I gave here to get more information on how it's done:

[Draw driving route between 2 GeoPoints on GoogleMap SupportMapFragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125868/draw-driving-route-between-2-geopoints-on-googlemap-supportmapfragment/16126547#16126547)